# SHAREPOINT VBA EXCEL ADDOB record addNew

Tags: sql, excel, vba, sharepoint

I can add new data in an empty list but when the list is filled. I have a problem when there are element in the list. I have the following message error message which display:
***"row handle referred to a deleted row or a row marked for deletion"***

Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit 
Sub AddNew_SP()
Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim mySQL As String
Dim intRowActive As Integer
Dim intcolumnActive As Integer

Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
intRowActive = ActiveCell.Row
intcolumnActive = ActiveCell.Column
 mySQL = "SELECT * FROM [test Prestations actif] WHERE [Test] = '" + Sheets("Plannification").Cells(intRowActive, 2).Value + "'And [Date] = #" + Format(Sheets("Plannification").Cells(6, intcolumnActive).Value, "dd/MM/yyyy") + "#;"


With cnt
    .ConnectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE= url;LIST={47D821D1-325A-44CC-A22A-E838B6C6B8E1};"
    .Open
End With

rst.Open mySQL, cnt, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

rst.AddNew
    rst.Fields(1) = "Nom1"
    rst.Fields(2) = "PréNom1"
    rst.Fields(3) = "addresse"



rst.Update

If CBool(rst.State And adStateOpen) = True Then rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
If CBool(cnt.State And adStateOpen) = True Then cnt.Close
Set cnt = Nothing

End Sub
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an INSERT statement

```vb
Sub AddNew_SP()

    Const mySQL = "INSERT INTO [test1] VALUES (?,?,?)"
    
    Dim cnt As new adodb.Connection
    With cnt
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;" & _
         "DATABASE= URL;LIST={47D821D1-325A-44CC-A22A-E838B6C6B8E1};"
        .Open
    End With
    
    Dim cmd As adodb.Command
    Set cmd = New adodb.Command
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = cnt
        .CommandText = mySQL
        .CommandType = 1 'adCmdText
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P1", adVarChar, 1, 10) ' varchar(10)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P2", adVarChar, 1, 10) ' 1 = adParamInput
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P3", adVarChar, 1, 10) '
    End With
    
    ' new record
    Dim n As Integer, ar
    ar = Array("Nom1", "PréNom1", "address")
    cmd.Execute n, ar
    
    MsgBox n & " record(s) inserted", vbInformation, "Done"
        
    If CBool(cnt.State And adStateOpen) = True Then cnt.Close
    Set cnt = Nothing
End Sub
```